# How to create a table with this layout?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, cline

Before requesting help I tried to find the way myself using `\cline` `\multicolumns` and `\multirows` without success.

How do I get the table with the layout below ?

[image: table layout]

**EDIT:**

my attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|m{3cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}*{text} & \multirow{2}*{text} & \multirow{2}*{text} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{text}\\
\cline{1-3}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost achieve what you like to have :-)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|m{3cm}|m{2cm}|m{2cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}*{text} & \multirow{2}*{text} & \multirow{2}*{text} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{text}\\
    \cline{4-5}
  &   &   & 4 & 5\\
    \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In that environment, which is similar to `{tabular}` (of `array`), you merge cells both vertically and horizontally with the command `\Block` and the key `hvlines` draws all the rules excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{2cm}m{2cm}m{3cm}m{2cm}m{2cm}}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{text} & \Block{2-1}{text} & \Block{2-1}{text} & \Block{1-2}{text}\\
  &   &   & 4 & 5\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]