# How to fit merged columns/rows content to the appropriate cell width?

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow, cline

What is the best way to make the red text fit the width of the merged cells/rows and automatically break the line instead of causing overflow to the next cell and cells content ?

PS: I never used package [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2,5cm}|p{2,5cm}|p{3cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}*{\textcolor{red}{this is a long text long}} & \multirow{2}*{here is a text} & \multirow{2}*{\textcolor{red}{this is a long text long}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{text}\\
    \cline{4-5}
  &   &   & \textcolor{green}{it works here text} & here is a text\\
    \hline
\multirow{3}*{text} & \multirow{3}*{\textcolor{red}{this is a long text long long}} &  \textcolor{green}{split like this long text } & \multirow{3}*{text} & \multirow{3}*{text}\\

  &   &   text & \\
  &   &   text & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The code follows: [How do i get a table with this layout?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/296162/92620)

Comment: you need to specify a width not `*` for multirow so it uses p column formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Carlisle said in his comment, instead `*` you need to declare width of column, for example for `multirow` in the first column:

```
\multirow{2}{2.5cm}{this is a long text long}
```

With this corection you will obtain:

[image]

The last vertical line is missed because you has in the last two rows only 3 ampersands instead four. By the way, LaTeX use decimal point, not comma.